# Comments on the page wont show up

Tags: php

Hello i have a problem i cant see the comments on the page. 
I dont get any error on the page so i am stuck on this moment
can somebody help me??

This is the php code:

```
<div id="container">
  <?php include('includes/menu.php');?>
        <div id="post">
            <?php
                $row = $query->fetch_object();
                echo "<h2>".$row->title."</h1>";
                echo "<p>".$row->body."</p>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="add-comments">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"?>" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label>Email Adres</label><input type="text" name="email" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Naam</label><input type="text" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Commentaar</label><textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $id?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Toevoegen"/>
            </form>
            </div>
            <hr />
          <div id="comments">
            <?php
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
                while($row = $query->fetch_object()):
            ?>
              <div>
                    <h5><?php echo $row->name?></h5>
                    <blockquote><?php echo $row->comment?></blockquote>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the rest of the page is:

```
    <div id="container">
  <?php include('includes/menu.php');?>
        <div id="post">
            <?php
                $row = $query->fetch_object();
                echo "<h2>".$row->title."</h1>";
                echo "<p>".$row->body."</p>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="add-comments">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"?>" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label>Email Adres</label><input type="text" name="email" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Naam</label><input type="text" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Commentaar</label><textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $id?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Toevoegen"/>
            </form>
            </div>
            <hr />
          <div id="comments">
            <?php
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
                while($row = $query->fetch_object()):
            ?>
              <div>
                    <h5><?php echo $row->name?></h5>
                    <blockquote><?php echo $row->comment?></blockquote>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Hope somebody see the problem.

Comment: You should end the div tag in your while loop, you have broken html.

Comment: Does the query return any results? Is there any database errors?

Comment: Where you putting id in $id?

Answer (score 0):

try like this for printing comments..

```
 <div id="comments">
            <?php
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
                while($row = $query->fetch_object()){ //opening while block
            ?>
              <div>
                    <h5><?php echo $row->name;?></h5>
                    <blockquote><?php echo $row->comment;?></blockquote>
            <?php }// ending while block ?>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: he dont create a post_id in my database how can i repairt that here a some pictures.

Structure of the database![enter image description here][1]


No post_id created:
![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CHpcM.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AD7Wy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="comments">
        <?PHP
            $query = $db->query("SELECT name, comment FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
            while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
        ?>
          <div>
                <h5><?= $row->name ?></h5>
                <blockquote><?= $row->comment ?></blockquote>
          </div>
        <?PHP  } ?>
 </div>
```

If that does not work, i would suggest dumping out the SQL query and making sure it is working.

Comment: he dont create a post_id in my database how can i repairt that here a some pictures.

Structure of the database![enter image description here][1]


No post_id created:
![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CHpcM.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AD7Wy.jpg